# Execute a program on Android with QProcess inside an APK

Tags: android, qt, apk, qprocess

I've a QT Android application (A) that needs to execute another application (B). The B application is packaged inside the A APK.

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
QString program ="B";
process->start(program, arguments);
```

What must to put on *program* variable to call B?

When the application was ported to iOS, will require any change?